# Guessing root of polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods

> Given $p(x)=x^5+(1+2i)x^4-(1+3i)x^2+8+44i$ check with the Horner-scheme if $(-2-i)$ is a root of $p(x)$.

First I have to guess a root, then proceed with the Horner-method and if i factorized it, i can say if $(-2-i)$ is a root or not, but how can i guess the first root, are there any tricks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(x) = 8 + 44i + x^2(-(1+3i) + x^2(1+2i + x))$

Now, let $x=-2-i$, thus, $x^2 = 4-1-4i = 3+4i$

$\begin{align}p(x) &= 8 +44i + (3+4i)(-(1+3i) + (3+4i)(-1+i)))\\
&=8+44i + (3+4i)(-(1+3i)  -3+3i-4i-4))\\
&=8+44i +(3+4i)(-1-3i-3+3i-4i-4)\\
&=8+44i + (3+4i)(-8 - 4i)\\
&=8+44i -24 -12i -32i +16\\
&=0
\end{align}
$

Thus $-2-i$ is a root.

Comment: Entirely giving away what clearly looks like a homework problem is perhaps not the most optimal thing to do the OP's education.

Comment: @gt6989b I have seen homework questions with proper attempts by this user before, so I am assuming that he tried on this one. I doubt he's using this site like an answer machine like some of the "1 rep wonders". It is just that, initially, I posted my attempts when asking for help with homework, but now I expect the community to understand that I am not a new user, and have probably already done my best in case I post homework, without needing to prove that by posting my attempt. I am just vesting the same trust in the OP.

Comment: Fair enough, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to factor the entire thing. $r$ is a root of $p(x)$ if and onyl if $p(r)=0$. So use Horner's scheme to evaluate $p(-2-i)$ and see if you get $0$ or not.